# How do I convert an Access 2007 DateTime to mysql datetime format?

Tags: c#, mysql, ms-access, datetime, format

I have a database (Access 2007) and want to represent a datetime field as a Mysql datetime format.
For example, "23.02.2011 12:23:01" as "2011.02.23 12:23:01".

I'm using SQL to Access from C# (OLE DB connection).

What stored functions of Access can I use?

Example:

```
select FUNCTION_NAME(DateTimeField, "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss") from tableName;
```

What's the FUNCTION_NAME I need?

Comment: Rob, thank you for the editing.

Comment: This is a presentation-level issue and I don't think it belongs in SQL.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton It belongs in SQL if the intention is to transfer data.

Comment: Only if your database interface doesn't understand proper translation of date data types between the two databases. That is, when I export an Access table to MySQL via an ODBC DSN, the dates come out just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about Format?

```
 select Format(DateTimeField, "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss") from tableName;
```